# Sending a PHP Form with PhoneGap

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, cordova

Last thread was riddled with errors, made a mistake when pasting it.

To start off, I've been playing around with PhoneGap, and what I'm trying to do eventually is build an app with a contact form that will email the results to an email of my choice (along with a picture taken in the camera app) (or post results to a server even)

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597891/phonegap-contact-form-not-working-over-php) and I've been trying to replicate it to get a starting feel of how my form would work, however, I can't seem to get it running.

Heres a step by step of what I have so far.

Index.html -> Just links to callsheet.html

callsheet.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Send in CallSheet</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


    // Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
</script>

  </head>
  <body>
<form action="http://contest.phoenixamd.com/ANDROIDTEST/callsheet.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-element">

        <label for="msg">Message</label>
        <textarea id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="required" rows="5" required ></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="button" value="submit contact"/>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

callsheet.php (on my remote server)

```
    <?php
    require_once("class.phpmailer.php");


    $MessageText=$_POST["msg"];


    $mailer = new PHPMailer();
    $mailer->isSMTP();
    $mailer->CharSet='utf-8';
    $mailer->AddAddress("gabesteinberg@me.com", "Gabe");
    $mailer->Subject="Mobile App Message";
    $mailer->From = 'test@phoenixamd.com';
    $mailer->Body = $MessageText;


    //VALIDATION
    if(
    empty($MessageText)
    ) {
        echo "Error";
    } else {
        $mailer->Send();
        echo "Success";
    }

?>
```

index.js (where im keeping my jquery)

```
    // When the document has loaded...
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Bind this action as a function to be executed when the button is clicked...
  $('input[type="button"][value="submit"]').click(function() {
    $.post('http://contest.phoenixamd.com/ANDROIDTEST/callsheet.php', {


      MessageText: $('#msg').val()

      // HTML function

      }, function (html) {
          // Place the HTML in a astring
          var response=html;

          // PHP was done and email sent
          if (response=="Success") {
            alert("Message sent!"); 
          } else {

            // Error postback
            alert("Please fill all fields!"); 
            return false;
          }
    });
  });
});
```

I've tried following steps taken [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711074/using-php-form-inside-phonegap) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697566/phonegap-native-app-submit-form-through-php-mailer-on-live-server) but cant seem to figure out whats wrong... When I hit submit, absolutely nothing happens.

My PHP file works, and if I submit via [this](http://contest.phoenixamd.com/ANDROIDTEST/callsheet.html) it echoes success and sends the email.

If I change my php to submit instead of button, it works, but thats just using the html and php, not the actual JS of the app itself.

Comment: Is there anything in your JS error console?

Comment: Oh its saying Cannot open file for reading.

Comment: Is this a cross domain request?

Comment: Im trying to send a form from my phone to contest.phoenixamd.com/ANDROIDTEST/callsheet.php

Comment: I mean, is the page that you have the JS running on, on the same domain as the page it's trying to post to?

Comment: The JS is in my PhoneGap package, not on my webserver aswell.

Comment: Ah sorry, I mistook how phonegap worked.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i don't think the request will be allowed if your domain is not whitelisted in `config.xml`.

I cannot tell from your text on which device your example fails - if i was on android i'd just grep the logcat output for any errors, which the CordovaWebView will send there by default.

Comment: Added the domain to the whitelist, now its skipping straight to Error as soon as I launch the app

Comment: <!--  <content src="http://contest.phoenixamd.com/ANDROIDTEST/callsheet.php" />-->

If I uncomment that, It errors immediately.

Comment: I was expecting you to add s.th. like <access origin="contest.phoenixamd.com*"/> . Never seen the contant-tag you're describing . Furthermore: What is the type of the error, what does it say? What is the platform / device you're testing on?

Answer (score 0):

In your html file, your input type="button" should have been input type="submit", try this out I have had this problem a few times myself....